# index list error google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

```
file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/ms-excel', _blobinfo_uploaded_filename='sample.xls')
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    sheet = wbk.add_sheet('Sheet 1')
    stringa = str(newfile.text)
    s3 = stringa.split('\n')
    i=1
    for riga in s3:
        s2=riga.split()
        try:
            x  = float(s2[0])
            y = float(s2[1])
            sheet.write(i, 1, '%g' %x)
            sheet.write(i, 2, '%14.3e' %y)
        except:
            sheet.write(i, 1, '%s' %s2[0])
            sheet.write(i, 2, '%s' %s2[1])
        i=i+1
```

File "/base/data/home/apps/s~marco-busso/1.357756583016056739/helloworld.py", line 140, in post
    sheet.write(i, 1, '%s' %s2[0])
IndexError: list index out of range

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `s2` is empty, which means `riga` is an empty string. Does `stringa` have more than one `'\n'` in a row? Check `newfile.text`, maybe the is an empty line there.

To prevent the error, you can wrap the loop body in an `if` statement, such as:

```py
for riga in s3:
    if riga:
        s2=riga.split()
        try:
            x  = float(s2[0])
            y = float(s2[1])
            sheet.write(i, 1, '%g' %x)
            sheet.write(i, 2, '%14.3e' %y)
        except:
            sheet.write(i, 1, '%s' %s2[0])
            sheet.write(i, 2, '%s' %s2[1])
        i=i+1
```

Comment: Of course. For instance, you can wrap the contents of the `for` loop in an `if riga:` statement.

Comment: Good. May I also point out that usually helpful answers are [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) by the asker to indicate that the problem is resolved. This also applies to your previous question.